# Google Search Console shows "incompatible plugins" in the mobile usability report despite not using Flash, how do I diagnose the cause?

Tags: google-search-console, plugin, mobile-friendly-tool

Google Search console is giving me a 'Uses incompatible  plugins' error for mobile usability for a number of my pages, including https://www.crn.com/sp-500/sp2020.htm and https://www.crn.com/sp-500/sp2019.htm.
We certainly don't have Flash or anything like that running - is it possible that jQuery 1 is an 'incompatible plugin'?

Updated to include error screen. Error is not specifically indicated in HTML, Screenshot or 'More info' views. It may be social sharing scripts, or other js, perhaps.

[image]

Comment: Google's [help document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9063469?hl=en) only mentions Flash as incompatible.  I'm not sure how you are supposed to figure out what plugin they are complaining about.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up comment - I agree Google is being opaque here! But I appreciate I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: [This site](https://serpstat.com/blog/how-to-disable-plugins-for-the-mobile-version-of-a-website/) lists some other plugins that get flagged: Java, Silverlight, and some video formats.   You do have video on those pages which plays on my Android phone, but maybe it is detecting the video as incompatible erroneously?

Answer (score 1):

This appears be a known issue with the BrightCove video player that you are using.   They have a [workaround in their API documentaton](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-options.html#suppressnotsupportederror):

> #### `suppressNotSupportedError`
>
> Type: `boolean`
>
> If set to `true`, then the "no compatible source" error will not be triggered immediately and instead will occur on the first user interaction. This is useful for Google's "mobile friendly" test tool, which can't play video but where you might not want to see an error displayed.

You should be able to use that setting to prevent the mobile friendly tool from seeing the problem. (Although as I said in the comments, the video seems to play fine, at least on my mobile device, so I'm not sure there actually is a problem at all.)

Comment: Good find - I'll check it out - thanks